# The difference between putting functions into an object and prototyping them?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between adding functions to an object and prototyping them onto the object?

Prototyping allows the object/model to call itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "model"? An object with properties that reference functions would be a singleton, whereas a function as constructor that when called with `new` returns an object with properties that reference functions can be used to create multiple objects.

Comment: Yes, do elaborate on the question.  I think nnnnnn's guess as to what your question is getting at is correct (e.g. the difference between the built-in object's `Math` and `Date` is a good example), but it would nice to be absolutely sure what you are getting at.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "object of functions" is typically used to "namespace" a set of functions so that there is one container object with numerous methods rather than numerous global functions. The benefit is in keep code components categorised or grouped by the object (and perhaps an object hierarchy), there are no benefits to performance and if global functions are thoughtfully named, there should be no reasonable chance of a naming collision. That is, the primary purpose is to create neat, logical groups of functions.

By "prototyping methods" I presume you mean using a constructor to create instances. Constructors and prototypes are used where inheritance is required, they are quite a different strategy to "namespaceing", the use of one does not preclude the other. It is quite reasonable to use prototypes for inheritance and use an "object of functions" to group the instances (and constructors for that matter).

Comment: Suggested edits before +1ing: (1) the OP didn't say "protyping _methods_" and (2) constructors and prototypes are used where _multiple instances_ are required, not _inheritance_.  Well technically they are required for inheritance but I think you make a stronger point with multiple instances.  Contrast `Math` and `Date`.  We don't necessarily use inheritance with `Date` but it differs from `Math` in having multiple instances.

Comment: Hey cool, someone decided to downvote a bunch of my answers, probably because I had the gall to point out a glaring error in one of his/her answers. I don't really know because they didn't have the guts to say who they were. I guess that makes my Stackoverflow experience complete. :-)

Comment: @Ray Toal - prototypes exist for inheritance, but there is no requirement that they *must* be used for inheritance, i.e. you don't have to create multiple instances (though it only really makes sense to use them if that is the intention). Date and Math are totally different objects. Date is a constructor, instances inherit methods from Date.prototype. The Math object is a plain object, it's not a constructor (no internal construct property), nor a function (no internal call method). Its internal prototype is Object.prototype (ECMA-262 §15.8) so it inherits nothing from Function.prototype.

Comment: +1 well put.  I tend to read the unqualified term "inheritance" as classical rather than prototypal inheritance, but it _is_ clear from your comment you meant prototypal, so a well-deserved accept.  (PS interesting SO "experience" story... why can't people just thank others for pointing out errors?)

Comment: It is an unfortunate consequence of the "reputation" system that people are offended when down voted. I really don't care, just as long as they tell me what's wrong. If I get a downvote wrong I'm quite happy to correct it if my error is revealed. Note that if an answer is downvoted, the poster can get their "reputation points" back by deleting it. Sometimes I simply correct the answer if the intention is clear but it's technically awful. Maybe they get some points, good for them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is coding example.

```
// when defining "Bla", the initial definition is copied into the "prototype"
var Bla = function()
{
    this.a = 1;
}
// we can either modify the "prototype" of "Bla"
Bla.prototype.b = 2;
// or we can modify the instance of "Bla"
Bla.c = 3;

// now lets experiment with this..

var x = new Bla();  // read: "clone the prototype of 'Bla' into variable 'x'"  
alert(x.b);     // alerts "2"
alert(x.c);     // undefined   -- because "c" doesn't exist in the prototype
alert(Bla.c);   // alerts "3"  -- "Bla" is an object, just like your instance 'x'

// also note this:
Bla.a = 1337;
var y = new Bla();
alert (y.a);    // alerts "1"  -- because the initial definition was cloned, 
                // opposed to the current state of object "Bla"
```