# require() turns constructor's functions to prototypes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

There is just one behavior of `javascript` or specifically `node.js' require()` that I like to understand. I already read this:

[Adding new properties to constructor function without .prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582341/adding-new-properties-to-constructor-function-without-prototype)

and this:

[The difference between putting functions into an object and prototyping them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382727/the-difference-between-putting-functions-into-an-object-and-prototyping-them)

But if you use `require()` http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require to create new object like:

```
var Ftp = require("jsftp"),
    ftp = new Ftp({
      host: "ftp.mywebsite.com",
    });
```

And then let say if you do `ftp.getPutSocket()` later, it's actually calling the original `Ftp.getPutSocket = function() {}` in **jsftp.js** file.

Now how could it be? I thought if you do `new Something()`, you can only call into `Ftp.prototype.getPutSocket`. So did `require()` did some magic here?

**UPDATE 1:**

So it's nothing to do with `require()` but basically a `function.call(Ftp.prototype)` line that the end. But how come this gave me error:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/7j3Vp/

```
var Test = function() {
    console.log('aa');
}

(function() {
    this.anotherTest = function() {
        console.log('bb');
    }
}).call(Test.prototype);
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

I tried to do the same thing as https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/blob/master/lib/jsftp.js

Comment: Could you post how you defined that `getPutSocket` function in *jsftp.js*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `getPutSocket` is defined (https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/blob/master/lib/jsftp.js#L620), `this` is actually `Ftp.prototype` (see https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/blob/master/lib/jsftp.js#L803).

So it doesn't look like Ftp.getPutSocket is defined at all. It is only defined on `Ftp.prototype`.

#### Update 1:

This fails because of the order in which javascript evals things.  Functions first, then variable assignments.

This however, works:

```
function Test() {
    console.log('aa');
}

(function() {
    this.anotherTest = function() {
        console.log('bb');
    }
}).call(Test.prototype);
```

Comment: `function.call()` lets you call a function by setting the `this`.  The first parameter to `call` will be the value of `this` during the function execution.  You can also pass additional parameters that will be the parameters to the function (more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).  `function.apply` does the same thing, except you pass the parameters as an array.

Comment: I read through and still confused. Can you look at my UPDATE 1 in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error is because of JavaScript's [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). If you change your code to this:

```
function Test() {
    console.log('aa');
}

(function() {
    this.anotherTest = function() {
        console.log('bb');
    }
}).call(Test.prototype);
```

It will just work.

The reason for that is that there are some important differences between declaring a function like

```
function F() {} // Function declaration
```

and like

```
var F = function() {} // Function expression
```

In the first example, because of it being a declaration, `F` is parsed and evaluated before any other expressions are. That's why you can do things like:

```
console.log(myFun());

function myFun() {
  return 'Hi there!';
}
```

and it will work, even if you are declaring a function **after** it is used. On the other hand, if you would write it like

```
console.log(myFun());

var myFun = function() { // expression
  return 'Hi there!';
}
```

It wouldn't work, because the `var` expression is being executed after it is actually used, since it is an expression (it is a part of an assignment expression).

In your example, when `call` evaluates `Test.prototype` the `Test` function hasn't been assigned yet, and that's why you get that `TypeError`.

More good information and insights about this:

- http://kangax.github.io/nfe/
- http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html